# Scaling before anova?

Tags: normalization, bioinformatics, anova

I want to perform an anova analysis for identifying differentially expressed genes. Should I scale the data using quantile normalization or median absolute deviation before looking for differentially expressed genes or should I apply anova directly on data obtained through RMA?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can apply ANOVA after RMA, since it includes background adjustment, summarisation and quantile normalisation steps ([see here](http://bmbolstad.com/misc/ComputeRMAFAQ/ComputeRMAFAQ.html)).  For non-Affy data, something along the lines of log transformation/quantile normalisation or VST (variance stablilising transformation)/RSN (robust spline normalisation) for Illumina data could be used prior to ANOVA.

Best place for this question, as already pointed out is [BioStar](http://biostar.stackexchange.com).

By the way you will also want to do some filtering on the data after RMA and prior to ANOVA to remove probesets of low variance.  If you're working in R you will want to look at [genefilter](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/bioc-views/release/bioc/html/genefilter.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did not know about BioStar, that's exactly the website I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Always, always normalise, your results are simply not comparable otherwise. The normaisation technique to use depends largely on the microarray technology you are using.

For a more in-depth answer, you should try the [Biostar Stack Exchange site](http://biostar.stackexchange.com).